# Matching columns - in a Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Trying to see if I can build some logic around matching these columns. 
I have 2 tables

```
        Table A
    Make             Model
    BMW              2 Series
    BMW              3 Series
    BMW              3 Series GT
    BMW              5 Series
    BMW              5 Series GT
    BMW              7 Series
    Rolls-Royce      Other
    Mini             Cooper
    Mini             Coupe 


        Table B
    Make           Series
    BMW            2 Series
    BMW            3 Series
    BMW            5 Series
    Bavarian Motor 7 Series
    Rolls-Royce    42000 GT
    Mini           Cooper
```

I need extract the output as below and store in a table

```
    Output
    Make              Model_A        Model_B
    BMW              2 Series        2 Series
    BMW              3 Series        3 Series
    BMW              3 Series GT     3 Series
    BMW              5 Series        5 Series
    BMW              5 Series GT     5 Series
    BMW              7 Series        7 Series
    Rolls-Royce      Other           42000 GT  
    Mini             Cooper          Cooper
    Mini             Coupe           Cooper
```

For the most part, I could match the columns using the query below:

```
        ( A.SERIES like '%' + B.model + '%'
         OR B.model like '%' + A.series + '%' )
```

But this does not handle the "Coupe" vs "Cooper", Rolls-Royce nor the "BMW" vs "Bavarian Motor" cases.

Any idea how I can handle all these in T-sql or a query? Soundex nor any distance algorithm works in this instance - tried both.

I know I can handle all cases using a "union all" to run in a single query, but the key is to handle the above edge cases.

Thanks in advance for your help.
~Bee

Comment: You should fix your data so you have proper `join` keys.

Comment: You could add tables (`NormalizedMakes`, `NormalizedModels`) to provide normalized values, e.g. `Name` and `NormalizedName` columns and populate them accordingly with `('BMW', 'BMW'), ('Bavarian Motor Werks', 'BMW'),...`. Then use them to look up normalized values for comparison. Ugly, requires constant maintenance, collisions are likely, ... . Or hire a hand sanitizer.

Comment: @Gordon  - unfortunately, fixing the data is not an option - its from multiple sources. _ yes, could add a mapper table but maintaining that will be a nightmare. Any way, I can determine coupe and cooper are similar?

Answer (score 0):

why not perform a `JOIN` on both table like below to get the matching Model and Series

```
select t1.Make,t1.Model as Model_A,
t2.Series as Model_B
from tableA t1 join tableB t2 
on t1.Make = t2.Make;
```

Answer (score 0):

I rather hesitate to suggest this, but it might work in your situation:

```
    ( A.SERIES like '%' + B.model + '%'
     OR B.model like '%' + A.series + '%' ) or
     SOUNDEX(A.series) = SOUNDEX(b.model)
```

`SOUNDEX()` has so many problems that there is really no reason to use it -- unless you work for the Census Bureau and want to classify last names for future references subject to spelling variations.  But, you may find it useful for this specific problem.